# SharePoint 2013 Error - PersistedNavigationTermSetSyncJobDefinition

Tags: 2013, error

I'm using SharePoint 2013 with two Application Servers + a SQL server.

I have a strange error on my two app server in the event viewer, and I can't find anything on google about it :

> Execute method of job definition 
>        Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.PersistedNavigationTermSetSyncJobDefinition  (ID 3edb31d2-64a6-4ae9-b43f-0ebe00d0b1b5)  threw an exception.
>
> Users right are not enough to perform this action.

By the way, everything is working fine ... No error on the CentralAdmin.

Is [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/81006638-1bf7-432b-b2a5-522cc256b145/stuck-with-security-token-service) related ? Should I add the app pool account (of the web app using **FBA**) to **Local security Policy** with **Impersonate a client after authentication** ?

(P.S : Sorry for the last sentence in the error, I did the traduction myself).

Comment: Any help appreciated since I do not know if this error is really critical or not. TIA